# Unity Playscape SDK, Black screen on android device and crash after several seconds

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

With latest Playscape SKD version (unity package from 7.23.2015) we managed to make android apk file.

All post process scripts run without errors. But when Android application starts only black screen appear and no Unity-tagged scene initialization logs reached. Android system offers to close application after few seconds. There are some errors taken with android monitor: http://pastebin.com/7xspS2ea
Unity version 4.6.7f1

Has anyone an idea in which direction should we investigate this problem?

Also we have stripped google play service library with this config http://pastebin.com/pNC0i2fS to fit 65k method limit, may be this can be related.

Comment: After a complete recreation of the project and installing only openIAB, google play and Playskape SDK libraries we managed to get application running. But on application start playscape activity crashes with following exception: http://pastebin.com/PA57qEBj Playscape sdk functionality like banners or catalog does not work. This stack trace looks like playscape cant find any ads services I assume.

Comment: After further reserch I found a curious fact that application will crash completely if  there is android:name="com.playscape.playscapeapp.PlayscapeApp" attribute in application xml tag in AndroidManifest. If this tag is absent only playscape activity will crash but app will further launch normally.

Comment: https://github.com/Playscape/PublishingKit-Demo-Unity same errors on android build

Comment: here is the link to non functional demo apk build if it will help https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XoX7QQppAuZElfb2JNYl92ak0/view?usp=sharing